# Django app not working on mobile only (desktop is fine)?

Tags: python, django, security, intranet

I'm running a Django app on a private intranet which requires either the company wifi to access or, alternatively, a VPN connection in order to open it from a non-company wifi channel. That's working as intended.

The issue is that I can access the site from mobile (iPhone, iPad) when I'm on the company wifi. But when I'm connected through public wifi, *even if I'm connected via VPN and I can access the intranet*, I cannot access the site.

For a variety of security reasons I can't disclose precise details or code, so I'm not looking for an explicit solution. Instead, I would be very, very grateful for some general ideas as to what might possibly be causing this, or things that I could start looking into and/or check.

I know this isn't your typical stack overflow post, but it is definitely useful for me and I believe helpful to anybody else who runs into a similar issue if we can create a list of possible reasons for this error.

Comment: _I cannot access the site_ What happens when you try?  Do you get a specific http status code, or a timeout, or what?

Comment: Can you access other apps on the private intranet from mobile public wifi + vpn?